# Using FFmpeg native libraries with Android-NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ffmpeg, decoding

I could write a simple "Hello World" app and got it to compile and run ok, I know how to setup basic structure of an Android project to use native libraries. Could any one tell me how to use FFmpeg libraries to decode a video;

- How to write a .cpp file to decode a video file using the libraries(Open, Decode, Save)
- How to setup source files(in my case .cpp files) with `Android.mk` file

Please could anyone help.

Comment: couple links: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/       http://rowntreerob.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/ffmpeg-on-android-adding-vmware-and-ubuntu-to-best-practice/

Comment: Two more: https://github.com/offlinehacker-playground/rdrive/blob/master/ffmpeg-android-tutorial/README or http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html